# Open URL in specific size from Outlook Addin

Tags: c#, angularjs, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook addin and a website in AngularJs.

When I click a specific button in Outlook I want the website to open up. This works great with

```
Process.Start(url);
```

However, I would really like to start the website in a specific pixel width. Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

May be can you give a try to pass the parameters in the URL and on the site you can set the pixels by intercepting the url.

Comment: I need you to elaborate this. Can I set a width of the site from the website itself? And I don't mean the html width, but I mean the browser width

Comment: Yes. By using $location you can grab the parameters of the url and $window decides the size of the browser.

Comment: I need an example of this. Afaik it is only possible to do something on window resize event, but not actually resize the window using it.